# I have yearly sales forecast and constant seasonality (% of yearly sales). How can I come up with a seasonality that smooths the monthly growth?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, finance

Let's say I have a yearly sales forecast (in $), such as `{100,300,400,500}`

I also have a monthly seasonality percentage (as % of total yearly sales), such as `{5%,5%,15%,15%,10%,5%,10%,5%,10%,5%,10%,5%)`.

If I multiply December's percentage over Year 1, I would get the number `5`, as `5%*100=5`.

Yet, If I multiply January's percentage over Year 2, I would get the number `15`, as `5%*300=15`.

Although being correct in terms of %, such monthly growth rate is rather unusual.

How can I adapt the seasonality percentage to avoid unusual steps in a monthly sales forecast? I've tried to weight a CAGR growth but that didn't work.

As an answer, I would have a single seasonality percentage vector that would smooth out the monthly growth across 5 different years.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Any staisfactory response would be at least empirical, at least to deal with the point that you have a strong trend on top of your stated seasonality.

In particular, do the $5\%$ you state for January and December take account of the steady growth? Or are they the seasonal patterns you might expect to see in a steady state? In other words, do you want January figures to match the next December or the precededing December?  From your comments, I will assume the latter.

What you need to do is

(a) find a smooth trend curve that fits the annual forecasts to smooth monthly foreceasts over the $48$ months;

(b) adjust these monthly forecasts by your sesonality percentages (e.g. multiply the smooth monthly forecasts by the percentages and by $12$); and

(c) adjust the results slightly so that they add up to the correct totals and are sensible across year-ends and anything else you might need such as integer values

For example, you could end up with some pattern like this

```
     Month 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
           == == == == == == == == == == == ==
 Year 1     1  2  9 11  9  5 11  6 14  7 16  9
 Year 2    10 11 36 40 29 15 32 17 35 18 38 19
 Year 3    19 20 58 58 39 19 40 20 41 21 43 22
 Year 4    23 24 70 72 49 25 52 26 52 27 53 27
```

noting that each January is less than $5\%$ of its year's total and each December is more than $5\%$ of its year's total, but that this is due to the trend rather than the seasonality factors